# Providing special effects for image in UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uikit

In my app I would like to give motion to my image in `UIImageView`.

For example, when a button is clicked it should redirect to another view controller. When that view controller is loaded an image should appear with some special effect. I have searched how to do this, but can only find this done by using an array of images. I want to know if it is possible to animate a single image without using array of images.

Comment: how to show your image means what kind of animation you want?

Comment: You will need to tell us what kind of animation you have in mind in some more details. Like, would you like the image to scale/shrink/move/skew,... or is it more like a drawn pixel animation where a little man starts walking?

Comment: i mean like flip from left,zooming,dissolving and all..

Answer (score 1):

Yes - it is possible to animate a single image.  A number of view properties (frame, bounds, center, transform, alpha, backgroundColor, and contentStretch) can be animated with the `UIView` animation methods.

For example, to "dissolve" a `UIImageView`:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
    imageView.alpha = 0.f;
}];
```

In the above example, the image view would fade away over a 2 second period.

For a "flip from left" animate a transform.

Also, [core animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) provides additional animation capabilities.